# how to get value of select option and assign it to url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-parameters

I have a select drop down and each option has a value of something like "?add-to-cart=31".  I need a way so that when an option is clicked that it will assign the selected options value to the page url and reload the page (with the new parameter).

I have this:

```
jQuery("#landing-select option").click(function(){
addtocart();
})
function addtocart()
{
    window.location.href + $('#landing-select').val.delay(100000).onload;
    //alert('HI');

}
};
```

Am I missing something?  I would like it to add the options value to the browsers url and refresh the page.  I added the delay in there so the parameter had time to set to the url before the page reloaded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `+=` and .val()

```
 window.location.href += $('#landing-select').val().delay(100000).onload;
 //                   ^^                         ^^
```

Also .delay() wont work for this, use setTimeout instead

```
setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.href += $('#landing-select').val()
},100000);
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the value does not append itself to the current url as a parameter.  When I click on an option, nothing happens..  I tried using an alert instead and I see that so I am thinking it is something else, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `()` on the `.val` method. Should be `.val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href += "?valor="+$('#landing-select').val().delay(100000).onload;
```